GraphQL response: Permission denied
I am trying to request a GraphQL API endpoint with AWS IAM authentication and also assuming a role with elevated permissions.
Role is getting assumed successfully but GraphQL is sending 401
errorType: "UnauthorizedException"
message: "Permission denied"
Reuqest header:
:authority:
zrhicxhotfb5pafravgg6h6aaq.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
:method:
POST
:path:
/graphql
:scheme:
https
accept:
*/*
accept-encoding:
gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language:
en-US,en;q=0.9
authorization:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIATRDR7UP6GT7VFQXF/20241227/eu-west-1/appsync/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-user-agent, Signature=a63aba27b57d176bb864311a887cd1ed6aef34f510cfe0b574bc71f163960b27
content-length:
2388
content-type:
application/json; charset=UTF-8
origin:
http://localhost:3000
priority:
u=1, i
referer:
http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua:
"Google Chrome";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile:
?0
sec-ch-ua-platform:
"macOS"
sec-fetch-dest:
empty
sec-fetch-mode:
cors
sec-fetch-site:
cross-site
user-agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
x-amz-date:
20241227T210320Z
x-amz-security-token:
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
x-amz-user-agent:
aws-amplify/6.10.2 api/1 framework/1

And the code using API GraphQL (AWS AppSync)
import { AssumeRoleCommand, STS } from '@aws-sdk/client-sts';
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { generateClient } from 'aws-amplify/api';
import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
import { speedtestIam } from 'src/config';
import { triggerSpeedTest as triggerSpeedTestMutation } from '../../graphql/mutations';

// Define the triggerSpeedTest function
const triggerSpeedTestFn = async (args: { [x: string]: any; agentEndpointId?: any; type?: any; line?: any; }) => {
    const { agentEndpointId, type, line } = args;
    try {
      // Get the current credentials
      const { credentials: currentCredentials } = await fetchAuthSession();
  
      const sts = new STS({
        credentials: currentCredentials,
        region: 'eu-west-1'
      });
      
      const assumeXRole = async () => {
        try {
          const command = new AssumeRoleCommand({
            RoleArn: speedtestIam,
            RoleSessionName: `session-${Date.now()}`,
          });
  
          const role = await sts.send(command);
          console.log('Assumed IAM role:', role);
          return role;
  
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('An error occurred while assuming the role', error);
        }
        return undefined;
      };
      const role = await assumeXRole();
  
      if (role) { 
        console.log('Temporary credentials:', role.Credentials);
        // Configure Amplify with the temporary credentials
        Amplify.configure({
          API: {
            GraphQL: {
              endpoint: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_APPSYNC_ENDPOINT_USP,
              defaultAuthMode: 'iam',
              region: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AWS_REGION, // Optional
            },
          },
          Auth: {
            // Use Cognito Identity Pool configuration
            Cognito: {
              identityPoolId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // Your identity pool ID
            },
          },
        });
  
        // Create a new instance of the API client with the temporary credentials
        const apiClient = generateClient({
            authMode: 'iam',
        });
  
        // Trigger the speed test using the new API client
        const response = await apiClient.graphql({
          query: triggerSpeedTestMutation,
          variables: {
            authMode: 'AWS_IAM',
            input: {
              line,
              platform: 'JSClient',
              trigger: 'GRAPH_QL_API',
              type: type === 'TCP' ? 'TCPSpeedTestMT' : 'UDPSpeedTest',
            }
          }
        });
        return response;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`An error occurred while starting the speed test with agent endpoint id '${agentEndpointId}'`, error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

// Define the speedTestApi
export const speedTestApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'speedTestApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: '',
    }),
    tagTypes: ['SpeedTest'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        triggerSpeedTest: builder.mutation({
            query: triggerSpeedTestFn,
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useTriggerSpeedTestMutation } = speedTestApi;

